# Почему отправляется форма?

Tags: jquery, javascript

```
<form>
//Здесь динамически создается textarea
</form>
```

После нажатия enter в динамически созданном поле textarea сабмитится форма почему-то (get), хотя никаких submit button нет.

Comment: Может, js какой-то там вешается?

Comment: Когда убрал form тег - не отправляет...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте так: когда "разрешаете" отправку формы, вешайте на неё класс "can-submit".

```
$('#my-form').addClass('can-submit');
```

Ну и добавьте сам обработчик события на форму примерно такой:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
    if ($(this).hasClass('can-submit')) { return true; }
    else { return false; }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Форма с одним полем отправляется по enter, добавьте второе поле, и отправка пропадёт.

Comment: Не знал такой особенности...А если что-то вроде return false - который не сработал

Comment: Вы можете запретить отправку по Enter, повесив на поле событие: `onkeydown="if(event.keyCode==13){return false;}"`. Скрытые поля не учитываются, суть отправки по Enter в том, что форма не видит других элементов для заполнения, и если нажать enter при фокусе в единственном поле, форма отправляется.

Comment: Попробовал - не помогло...Вот сама форма: http://jsfiddle.net/wLqvpev8/

Comment: С одним инпутом да, но не с одной textarea.

http://jsfiddle.net/eLL6bh2c/

Comment: @mountpoint, да, так и есть, спасибо за уточнение.

@Oleg Ponomarchuk, судя по представленному вами коду, проблема похоже где-то в скриптах, попробуйте вынести все не относящиеся к форме элементы за её пределы.